# TCP buffer issue when publishing data from ESP32 on to mqtt broker

Tags: tcp, mqtt, iot, publish-subscribe, esp32

We are currently working on a project that involves sending IMU sensor data over MQTT broker using ESP32 Wi-Fi module. We are sending the data every 100milliseconds. It is too fast, as it is the need of the project. We need realtime data.

Whenever the ESP32 publishes the data(message) onto the broker we don't see the updations at broker immediately. Then we found out the issue that TCP buffer was buffering 2/3 messages and was publishing them together on broker.

So the behavior we expect is when subscribed to MQTT broker topic, we should be getting one set of data every 100ms. But because of this buffering issue, we are getting 2/3 sets of data together after 200/300ms which is uneven.

We are using PubSub client for ESP32-MQTT publishing.

Have anyone faced such issue and know the solution to this ?

Comment: WiFi, especially shared WiFi,  is not a reliable transmission medium for applications with stringent timing requirements. MQTT is also not designed and most brokers are not implemented to provide the type of service you’re looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!! Can you please suggest us other ways through which we can get the realtime data from the sensors with minimum latency.
We are using this realtime sensor data in our React app. So we tried using MQTT broker as it is the fastest way. To be honest, it is sending all the data in realtime, for e.g.: ESP32 is publishing every 100ms and when seen on the broker client we get approx 9-10 data messages per second..  but in groups of 2-3... that's the issue .. 
what we expect 100ms delay between 2 data messages... and we found out that TCP buffering is the reason for this.